# selenium trigger toolbar click

Tags: java, selenium

Chrome doesnt support fullpage screenshots.  So as a work around im thinking of using [full-page-screen-capture-chrome-extension](http://mrcoles.com/full-page-screen-capture-chrome-extension/)

This loads a new tab window as the previous page in a full image..

Looks good so far..

My question is.. In selenium can I trigger a mouse click on the toolbar?

How can I make selenium click this toolbar icon (Camera Icon) ?  It doesn't seem to offer any keyboard shortcut?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible with selenium since the GUI of chrome is not made up by HTML.

You can use a tool like [Sikuli Script](http://www.sikuli.org/) that allows to automate anything you see on screen using image recognition.